# not able to set readonly property of textboxes in a panel in windows form to true in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

i want to enable the read only property of all the text boxes in a panel in windows forms to true  during form load but  its not working. i am using the below code.when i am debugging the code it skips that part.not sure why??
The below code does not work,it skips that part as if there are no text box controls in the particular panel.

```
Private Sub lockgroupcontrols()
    For Each TextBox As TextBox In Pnltransaction.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()

        TextBox.ReadOnly = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct, so, I can only imagine that, if it skips the `For Each`, then you don't have any textboxes inside the `PnlTransaction` panel.

Sometimes this happens when you draw the Panel over preexisting textboxes. You think the controls are inside the panel, but in reality they are under the panel and you see them because the panel background is transparent.

Try to move the panel on a different place, drag&drop the textboxes over the panel and then reposition the panel.

Comment: perfect steve. i was about to answer my own question.when i checked it.the controls where not in the panel.thanks.i had drawn it over the existing controls

Comment: hi guys,if the above code is not working in your vb.net code then make sure to check that whether the container has all the controls inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use TextBox as name for your vars

```
   For Each **TextBox** As **TextBox** In
```

try it with for ex.

```
   ...For Each **tBox** As **TextBox** In 
         tBox.ReadOnly = True....
```